# Consul HA ACL init fail on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm, acl, consul, vault

I try to install Consul HA to configure my Vault HA on OpenShift platform. I am first using Consul Helm chart to install it and I can successfully install it using some SCC for my client and server serviceAccounts.
Later on, I wanted to deploy consul with ACL init through this helm but I am facing an error.

First installing consul with helm :

```
helm upgrade -i consul-ha --namespace vault consul/ --set ui.enabled=true --set global.acls.manageSystemACLs=true
```

Then my pods quickly go into error :

```
oc get pods
NAME                                             READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
consul-ha-consul-622vr                           0/1     Init:0/1            0          43s
consul-ha-consul-kxj4n                           0/1     Init:0/1            0          43s
consul-ha-consul-server-0                        0/1     Running             0          43s
consul-ha-consul-server-1                        0/1     ContainerCreating   0          43s
consul-ha-consul-server-2                        0/1     Pending             0          43s
consul-ha-consul-server-acl-init-8jf44           0/1     Error               0          33s
consul-ha-consul-server-acl-init-cleanup-dg5dk   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          14s
consul-ha-consul-server-acl-init-cleanup-xfq4m   0/1     Error               0          42s
consul-ha-consul-server-acl-init-l86r6           0/1     Error               0          43s
consul-ha-consul-wz4mf                           0/1     Init:0/1            0          43s
```

I get this error on describing acl-init pod :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age        From                Message
  ----     ------     ----       ----                -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>  default-scheduler   Successfully assigned vault/consul-ha-consul-server-acl-init-hrsk2 to compute-1
  Warning  Failed     2m12s      kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:46:12Z" level=warning msg="signal: killed"
time="2020-10-05T07:46:12Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:449: container init caused \\\"read init-p: connection reset by peer\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\""
  Warning  Failed  2m3s  kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:46:22Z" level=warning msg="signal: killed"
time="2020-10-05T07:46:22Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:365: sending config to init process caused \\\"write init-p: broken pipe\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:365: sending config to init process caused \"write init-p: broken pipe\""
  Warning  Failed  114s  kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:46:31Z" level=fatal msg="join_namespaces:542 nsenter: failed to open /proc/1372777/ns/ipc: No such file or directory"
time="2020-10-05T07:46:31Z" level=fatal msg="nsexec:724 nsenter: failed to sync with child: next state: Invalid argument"
time="2020-10-05T07:46:31Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \\\"EOF\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\""
  Warning  Failed  103s  kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:46:42Z" level=warning msg="signal: killed"
time="2020-10-05T07:46:42Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:449: container init caused \\\"read init-p: connection reset by peer\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\""
  Warning  Failed  94s  kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:46:51Z" level=warning msg="signal: killed"
time="2020-10-05T07:46:51Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:365: sending config to init process caused \\\"write init-p: broken pipe\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:365: sending config to init process caused \"write init-p: broken pipe\""
  Warning  Failed  81s  kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:47:04Z" level=fatal msg="join_namespaces:542 nsenter: failed to open /proc/1376195/ns/ipc: No such file or directory"
time="2020-10-05T07:47:04Z" level=fatal msg="nsexec:724 nsenter: failed to sync with child: next state: Invalid argument"
time="2020-10-05T07:47:04Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \\\"EOF\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\""
  Warning  Failed  73s  kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:47:12Z" level=fatal msg="join_namespaces:542 nsenter: failed to open /proc/1377778/ns/ipc: No such file or directory"
time="2020-10-05T07:47:12Z" level=fatal msg="nsexec:724 nsenter: failed to sync with child: next state: Invalid argument"
time="2020-10-05T07:47:12Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \\\"EOF\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\""
  Normal   SandboxChanged  62s (x8 over 2m12s)  kubelet, compute-1  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Failed          62s                  kubelet, compute-1  Error: container create failed: time="2020-10-05T07:47:23Z" level=warning msg="signal: killed"
time="2020-10-05T07:47:23Z" level=error msg="container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:449: container init caused \\\"read init-p: connection reset by peer\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\""
  Normal  Pulled  56s (x9 over 2m19s)  kubelet, compute-1  Container image "hashicorp/consul-k8s:0.18.1" already present on machine
```

I can't figure out what's going on. Any idea on this ?

Comment: Consul Helm version 0.25.0 was just released (Oct 12th, 2020) which includes support for deploying on OpenShift 4.x. See https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm/releases/tag/v0.25.0 for details.

I recommend upgrading to this version of the chart while being sure to set `global.openshift.enabled=true` during `helm install`, and see if this resolves your error.

Comment: OK I'll try it out and give feedback ASAP. Thanks